# Magento 2: How To Add Extension Attribute To order item only Order API

Tags: magento2, api, sales-order, extension-attributes

How To Add Extension Attribute To order item Order API

> Place order: [POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

Answer (score 1):

> [POST] rest/V1/carts/mine/items

Create cart then place order api hit.

> Place order: [POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

```
{
   "cartItem": {
   "sku": "test",
   "qty": 1,
   "quote_id": "10",
   "product_option": {
    "extension_attributes": {
      "custom_options": [
            {
               "option_id": "491",
               "option_value": "3057" // This should be the option string to show.
            }
         ]
     }
   }
  }
}
```